# CAKeyframeAnimation of "transform" is not animated alongside "opacity" in a CAAnimationGroup

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

What would be the reason for `CAKeyframeAnimation` objects to not be able to animate simultaneously in a `CAAnimationGroup`, but it does if being added individually to a `CALayer`?

A code snippet to describe this:

```
// The following is a part of CALayer extension function

let quadAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
quadAnimation.duration = 1.0
quadAnimation.repeatCount = 1
quadAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
quadAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
quadAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
quadAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.743, 0, 0.833, 0.833)

// Note:
// AGK-based methods come from a geometry manipulation library https://github.com/agens-no/AGGeometryKit
//   

var values: [NSValue] = []
let numberOfFrames = 30
for frame in 0..<numberOfFrames {
    let p = AGKEaseOutWithBezier(CGFloat(frame) / CGFloat(numberOfFrames))
    let quad = AGKQuadInterpolate(quad1, quad2, CGFloat(p))
    let innerQuad = AGKQuadMove(quad, -self.position.x, -self.position.y)
    let transform = CATransform3DWithAGKQuadFromBounds(innerQuad, CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.boundsSize))
    let value = NSValue(CATransform3D: transform)

    values += [value]
}

quadAnimation.values = values

let opacityAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
opacityAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 1]
opacityAnimation.values = [0, 1]
opacityAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.167, 0.167, 0.833, 0.833)
opacityAnimation.duration = 0.5
opacityAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.5
opacityAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

let animationBlockDelegate = AGKCALayerAnimationBlockDelegate()
animationBlockDelegate.onStart = {
    self.quadrilateral = quad2
}

let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
animationGroup.animations = [quadAnimation, opacityAnimation]
animationGroup.duration = quadAnimation.duration + opacityAnimation.duration + 0.5
animationGroup.delegate = animationBlockDelegate

CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
  // Completion block handler
}

self.addAnimation(animationGroup, forKey: "transformOpacityAnimationKey")

CATransaction.commit()
```

The opacity will be animated given the right `timingFunction` and `beginTime`, but the `CA3DTransform` values are not animated at all.

All of the above works fine if I added the animation individually to the layer:

```
self.addAnimation(quadAnimation, forKey:"quadAnimation")
self.addAnimation(opacityAnimation, forKey: "opacityAnimation")
```

With each animation `quadAnimation` and `opacityAnimation` process delegated to `AGKCALayerAnimationBlockDelegate()`

Comment: Your animation group has no duration. It needs to have an explicit duration that is at least long enough to encompass the durations of the child animations.

Comment: Okay, yes that's what I guess initially, but I have tried doing this. Let me update the snippet.